# First chaptertitles position & style problem

Tags: sectioning, chapters

[image: This]

This is how my document is looking. For the table of contents and introduction, I wanted to use a lighter block and no number, but there seems to be something wrong with the positioning of the block for my table of contents and somehow there keeps popping up a number 1. How can I remove the number 1 and put the box and text in the right place like?

[image: tableofcontents]
[image: inleiding]

EDIT:
It's working now, but the titles of my other chapters disappeared. I'd also like to get rid of the asterix. How can I fix this?

MWE:

Main document

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,textpos}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[vmargin=5cm,hmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles, explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge#1}

\titleformat{name = \chapter, numberless}[block]
 {\normalfont\Large\filleft}
 {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}
}%
 {10pt}{\Huge#1\rlap{\hskip0.5em\color{lightgray!50!}\rule[-0.5cm]{6cm}{1.5cm}}}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\newgeometry{
\topmargin -10mm
\textwidth 160truemm
\textheight 240truemm
\oddsidemargin 0mm
\evensidemargin 0mm
}

\definecolor{green}{RGB}{172,196,0}
\definecolor{bluetitle}{RGB}{29,141,176}
\definecolor{blueaff}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\definecolor{blueline}{RGB}{82,189,236}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}


\usepackage[style=verbose-inote, autocite=footnote, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\footcite}{\footcites}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\references.bib}
@article{pollard,
Author = {Foo Bar},
Date-Added = {2015-03-06 11:58:42 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2015-03-06 11:59:44 +0000},
Journal = {The Journal},
Pages = {147-162},
Title = {The Title},
Volume = {35},
Year = {2015}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\form}[1]{\scalebox{1.087}{\boldmath{#1}}}
\sffamily
%
\begin{textblock}{191}(-24,-11)
\colorbox{bluetitle}{\hspace{123mm}\ \parbox[c][18truemm]{68mm}{\textcolor{white}        {FACULTY}}}
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{70}(-18,-19)
\textblockcolour{}
\includegraphics*[height=19.8truemm]{UniversityLogo}
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{160}(-6,63)
\textblockcolour{}
\vspace{-\parskip}
\flushleft
\fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont \textcolor{bluetitle}{Thesis title}\\[1.5mm]
\fontsize{20}{22}\selectfont With a subtitle}
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{160}(8,153)
\textblockcolour{}
\vspace{-\parskip}
\flushright
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{My Name}
\end{textblock}

%
\begin{textblock}{160}(8,191)
\textblockcolour{}
\vspace{-\parskip}
\flushright
More information\\[4.5pt]
on my dissertation\\[4.5pt]
And my supervisor
\end{textblock}
   %
\begin{textblock}{160}(8,232)
\textblockcolour{}
\vspace{-\parskip}
\flushright
2014-2015
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{191}(-24,248)
{\color{blueline}\rule{550pt}{5.5pt}}
\end{textblock}
%
\vfill
\newpage

\rmfamily
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
%
\newpage
%
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
%
\input{introduction}
\input{methodology}
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
\input{chapter4}
%
\printbibliography
%
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\sffamily
%
\begin{textblock}{191}(113,-11)
{\color{blueline}\rule{160pt}{5.5pt}}
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{191}(168,-11)
{\color{blueline}\rule{5.5pt}{59pt}}
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{183}(-24,-11)
\textblockcolour{}
\flushright
\fontsize{7}{7.5}\selectfont
\textbf{Faculty name}\\
adress\\
city and country\\
tel. number\\
www.website.edu\\
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{191}(154,-7)
\textblockcolour{}
\includegraphics*[height=16.5truemm]{sedes}
\end{textblock}
%
\begin{textblock}{191}(-20,235)
{\color{bluetitle}\rule{544pt}{55pt}}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Introduction

```
\restoregeometry
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase*{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\addto\captionsdutch{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Introduction}}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\pagestyle{plain}

\section*{First section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Methodology (& next chapters)

```
\chapter{Methodology}

\section{First section of this chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

This is a dummy version of what I get. Don't mind the mix of languages and the messy front page. How can I get my chapter titles back?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and not code snippets.

Comment: Also, what's the difference between this question and your previous one http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228949/27635?

Comment: The other one was about how I could change the margins without changing the frontpage margins. That's ok now, but because nobody answered my question about the title blocks and I still didn't manage to fix it, I'm asking it again. Posting an MWE asap.

Comment: @karlkoeller MWE added!

Comment: @Password, After I cleared you MWE and removed all package clashes, everything is working and the result seems to be what you want to achieve! Consider removing multiple package loading, i.e., removing `\usepackage{xcolor}`, `\usepackage{geometry}`, `\usepackage{titlesec}` from your preamble. They are already being loaded with some options.

Comment: `\newgeometry` needs to go after `\begin{document}`. If you want to have this as a new question, edit your old one to focus on the original issue and accept the answer which you found most useful.